# C++ Office Excel Plugin Range QueryInterface "E_NOINTERFACE" Problem

Tags: c++, com, office-addins, excel-2013, office-2013

i created a plugin for ms office，it's works fine on office 2019 Excel & wps office 2019 ET，but it has problems on ms office 2013.

here is the describe:

```cpp
        rst = disp->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Excel::_Worksheet), (void**)&sheet);
        disp->Release();
        Excel::Range* rawRange = nullptr;
        Excel::IRange* rows = nullptr;
        rst = sheet->get_Rows(&rawRange);
        rst = rawRange ->QueryInterface( __uuidof(Excel::IRange), (void**)&rows);
```

the `get_Rows` works fine and returns S_OK，but Range::QueryInterface returns `E_NOINTERFACE`，that's  strange! I can not understand, is there anything i missed?

there are many positions called the `QueryInterface` method, but only the `Range` type query the `IRange` type will fail.

Office 2019 & WPS 2010 works fine，already reinstalled office 2013, but still no work. Maybe a Microsoft bug?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I can not answer your question, but give you a tip about it: you could improve its visibility by adding the `c++` and `office-2013` tags also.

Comment: thank for your advice, I'll add these topic tags.

Comment: Make sure your current thread is running as STA not MTA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize

Comment: thank for your reply, have read the document in the link, i found that Excel Addin does not need (can't) call the `CoInitializeEx` method, I Guess it's already invoked in Excel.exe so it can not specify the initialize flag

Comment: I have run across this problem in a large application I developed. My experience is that Microsoft does not always register older interfaces or they change somewhat. What I found to be the most reliable way to handle this problem is to only call methods on IDispatch ... in other words, use `Invoke` method. Just use the disp interface, don't query for the dual interface. CComDispatchDriver (or whatever it is called now), can make the process a little less painful. It's going to be a little more painful than calling the dedicated interface, but at least it will be more reliable. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valuable experience, my problems were completely solved in this way! thank you very much!@JosephWillcoxson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `@Joseph Willcoxson` says, the `Range` type did not implement the `IRange` interface but it implemented the features, we can use `IDispatch` interface `Invoke` method to do the same thing. and I'd like to share my utility code.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t ArrayLen(T(&ref)[N]) {
    return N;
}

enum class RangeDispID : DISPID {
    // Props
    NumberFormat    = 0x000000c1,
    Column          = 0x000000f0,
    Row             = 0x00000101,
    Rows            = 0x00000102,
    Columns         = 0x000000f1,
    Text            = 0x0000008a,
    Item            = 0x000000aa,
    Cells           = 0x000000ee,
    Count           = 0x00000076,
    Value2          = 0x0000056c,
    // Methods
    Select          = 0x000000eb,
    Find            = 0x0000018e,
    AutoFilter      = 0x00000319,
    Activate        = 0x00000130,
};

enum class WindowDispID : DISPID {
    FreezePanes     = 0x0000028a
};

enum class WorksheetDispID : DISPID {
    Rows            = 0x00000102,
    Range           = 0x000000c5,
    UsedRange       = 0x0000019c,
};

template<class T>
struct DispIDBridge {};

template<>
struct DispIDBridge<RangeDispID> {
    using DispIDType = RangeDispID;
    using UUIDType = Excel::IRange;
    DispIDBridge(DispIDType id) : id_(id){}
    operator DispIDType() const { return id_; }
    operator DISPID() const { return (DISPID)id_; }
private:
    DispIDType id_;
};

template<>
struct DispIDBridge<WindowDispID> {
    using DispIDType = WindowDispID;
    using UUIDType = Excel::IWindow;
    DispIDBridge(DispIDType id) : id_(id) {}
    operator DispIDType() const { return id_; }
    operator DISPID() const { return (DISPID)id_; }
private:
    DispIDType id_;
};

template<>
struct DispIDBridge<WorksheetDispID> {
    using DispIDType = WorksheetDispID;
    using UUIDType = Excel::_Worksheet;
    DispIDBridge(DispIDType id) : id_(id) {}
    operator DispIDType() const { return id_; }
    operator DISPID() const { return (DISPID)id_; }
private:
    DispIDType id_;
};

template<class T>
HRESULT DispSetProperty(IDispatch* obj, T id, CComVariant& val) {
    DISPID dispid = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
    DISPPARAMS params; {
        params.cNamedArgs = 1;
        params.rgdispidNamedArgs = &dispid;
        params.cArgs = 1;
        params.rgvarg = &val;
    }
    UINT errIn;
    auto rst = obj->Invoke(
        (DISPID)id,
        __uuidof(DispIDBridge<T>::UUIDType),
        chs_lcid,
        DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT,
        &params,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &errIn
    );
    return rst;
}

template<class T>
CComVariant DispGetProperty(IDispatch* obj, T id, CComVariant* args = nullptr, int argc = 0) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::reverse(args, args + argc);
    }
    CComVariant ret;
    DISPPARAMS params; {
        params.cNamedArgs = 0;
        params.rgdispidNamedArgs = nullptr;
        params.cArgs = argc;
        params.rgvarg = args;
    }
    UINT errIn;
    auto rst = obj->Invoke(
        (DISPID)id,
        __uuidof(DispIDBridge<T>::UUIDType),
        chs_lcid,
        DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
        &params,
        &ret,
        nullptr,
        &errIn
    );
    if (rst == S_OK) {
        return ret;
    }
    else {
        return CComVariant();
    }
}

template<class T>
HRESULT DispCallMethod(IDispatch* obj, T id, CComVariant* args, int argc) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::reverse(args, args + argc);
    }
    DISPPARAMS dispParams{};
    dispParams.cArgs = argc;
    dispParams.rgvarg = args;
    UINT errIn;
    auto rst = obj->Invoke(
        (DISPID)id,
        __uuidof(DispIDBridge<T>::UUIDType),
        chs_lcid,
        DISPATCH_METHOD,
        &dispParams,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &errIn
    );
    return rst;
}

template<class T>
CComVariant DispCallMethodWithRet(IDispatch* obj, T id, CComVariant* args, int argc) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::reverse(args, args + argc);
    }
    DISPPARAMS dispParams{};
    dispParams.cArgs = argc;
    dispParams.rgvarg = args;
    UINT errIn;
    CComVariant ret;
    auto rst = obj->Invoke(
        (DISPID)id,
        __uuidof(DispIDBridge<T>::UUIDType),
        chs_lcid,
        DISPATCH_METHOD,
        &dispParams,
        &ret,
        nullptr,
        &errIn
    );
    assert(rst == S_OK);
    return ret;
}
```

we can use it in this way

```
        CComVariant top5Row; {
            CComVariant args[] = {cellLoc};
            top5Row = DispGetProperty(sheet, WorksheetDispID::Range, args, ArrayLen(args));
        }
```